# how to use a map in evenlistener in javascript

Tags: javascript, maps, event-listener

my code works with the map ,m, until i use it on the event listener clicking the button, after that is throws an error and tells me m.get() is not a function, however works prior to the click event, what can i do to fix this and why is this happening??

```
'use strict';

const poll = {
    question: 'What is your favourite programming language?',
    options: ['0: JavaScript', '1: Python', '2: Rust', '3: C++'],
    // This generates [0, 0, 0, 0]. More in the next section 
    answers: new Array(4).fill(0),
    registerNewAnswer(m){
        const answer = Number(prompt(`${this.question}\n${this.options.join('\n')}`));
        answer < 4 && answer >= 0 ? answer : alert('invalid entry try again');
        //console.log(answer);
       m.set(this.options[answer],m.get(poll.options[answer]) + 1)
        
    }
    
}
const fun = function(arr){
    let narr =[];
    for(let i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
        let temp = [];
        temp.push(arr[i]);
        temp.push(0);
        narr.push(temp);
    }
    return narr;
}

const m = new Map(fun(poll.options));

const pollPrompt = poll.registerNewAnswer.bind(poll);
pollPrompt(m);

document.querySelector('.poll').addEventListener('click',poll.registerNewAnswer.bind(poll));
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is when the callback is run on `click`, `m` points to the `HTMLDOMNode` and not `map`

You can do the following:

```
const poll = {
    question: 'What is your favourite programming language?',
    options: ['0: JavaScript', '1: Python', '2: Rust', '3: C++'],
    // This generates [0, 0, 0, 0]. More in the next section 
    answers: new Array(4).fill(0),
    registerNewAnswer(m){
        console.log('m', m);
        const answer = Number(prompt(`${this.question}\n${this.options.join('\n')}`));
        answer < 4 && answer >= 0 ? answer : alert('invalid entry try again');
        //console.log(answer);
       m.set(this.options[answer],m.get(poll.options[answer]) + 1)
        
    }
    
}
const fun = function(arr){
    let narr =[];
    for(let i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
        let temp = [];
        temp.push(arr[i]);
        temp.push(0);
        narr.push(temp);
    }
    return narr;
}

const m = new Map(fun(poll.options));

const pollPrompt = poll.registerNewAnswer.bind(poll);
pollPrompt(m);

document.querySelector('.poll').addEventListener('click', () => { 
  poll.registerNewAnswer(m) 
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it all makes sense. the course had me to set on trying to use bind, i was looking in the wrong place, in eventlisteners all the this keywords point at the dom instead of the function

Comment: @Ryan thanks. could you please accept and upvote? :)